# how to change color of each letter of <p> with just css

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I am trying to change each letter styles but **I'm restricted from using `javascript` and without using span for each letters** , I searched  got some pseudo `nth-letter` but this not working , I know this type of question asked before but the restrictions force me to add this question.

please give some suggestions , it is really helpful

```css
.change:nth-letter(3)
{
color:red;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="change"> Color </p>
```

Comment: Can you use CSS? What does "I have restricted to use javascript" mean?

Comment: yes but cannot use javascript and also cannot give span like elements for each letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a ***hack*** that uses:

- a *monospace* font so that each letter has a uniform width
- *inline* display so that the width of the container is as much as its text
- uses *experimental* [**`background-clip: text`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Values) to *clip* the background on to the text
- uses a `linear-gradient` to color each letter

See demo below:

```css
.change {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: inline;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color:transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 40%, red 40% 60%, black 60%);
}
```

```html
<p class="change"> Color </p>
```

Comment: great mind really it will works , but need extra efforts :)

Answer (score -2):

I think, you cannot use pseudo elements as `:second-letter` or `:third-letter`. The possible way to select first and last word follow below.

```css
.hello:first-letter {
  color:red;
}
.hello:after {
  color: red;
  content: "r";
}
```

```html
<p class="hello">Colo</p>
```